# why do we use "were" instead of "was" in second conditional sentences?

Tags: sentence, conditionals, syntactic-analysis

I have usually noticed that often in second conditional sentences "were" is used instead of "was". After trying to understand some concepts I couldn't understand its reason .I will be glad if you guys could help me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I wish father were* here.

In this sentence were* is genuine past subjunctive for an unreal wish. Father is not here, but the child wishes it. The asterisk is my sign for subjunctive form.

As the form were* is the only case where past indicative and past subjunctive have different forms - in all other cases the forms are alike - the genuine past subjunctive is mostly replaced by "was", a substitute for the genuine subjunctive.

In the sentence "I wish father was* here" the form was has the sense of a subjunctive.

The conjugation table of Verbix.com shows the subjunctive forms http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html

In unreal if-clauses a form of past tense (if I had, if I did, if I went) that looks like a normal past (indicative) is in reality a past subjunctive. Unfortunately in English the forms are alike whereas in other languages (German, French etc) they are different.

Comment: If the forms are alike  except for a few exceptions, perhaps it's time to stop using the same term.